# How Cloning Breaks singleton

Tags: singleton

1) Singleton means the class have one instance. Having private constructer. No way to create object except reflection. No subclassing.
If i want to clone my singleton classthen class must and should implement Cloneable and override clone() right. 
am not going to implement Cloneable interface in my Singleton class. 
 Then how cloning breaks my singleton. is this correct. Please clarify some one. if am wrong.

what is the need of throwing clonenotsupported exception.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking for. When you have a singelton - there is **no point** in serializing it, or making it cloneable?!

Comment: Some of the tutorials i found like cloning ,Reflection and serialization breaks singleton. By using reflection we can set constructor as set accessible and we can create object i agree. But in case of cloning and serialization hoe it breaks. My singleton class any one can use but they cant change code rt. The how it's breaks. I think now you got some idea what am asking.

Comment: If someone wants to break your code you can't prevent that. Simply start by making your singleton not clone able or Serializable. Don't invest time in protecting against such things.

Answer (score 0):

No reason to implement Cloneable and override clone() to throw CloneNotSupportedException. Object. Clone, throws expectation when the Cloneable interface is absent.

The correct way to create singleton class using enums can be referred in my favorite java book "Effective Java" . Please read that.